# Type for setting initial state on arrays

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, redux-toolkit, react-typescript

I am a little new to typeScript can anyone identify what would be the type of FilteredCars array in initialState object , the code is from a redux-toolkit slice, i am using react for the project

```
type  FilteredCarsProps = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  address: string
}

interface initialStateProps {
  isFiltered: boolean,
  Filters : object,
  [FilteredCars: number]: FilteredCarsProps
}


export const initialState :initialStateProps={
  isFiltered: false,
  Filters : {},
  FilteredCars: [] //<====== This variable
}
```

I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing the types, generally you copy paste what ever your object looks like and change the values to types.  In this case:

```
interface initialStateProps {
   isFiltered: true, // I change true to boolean
   Filters : {}, // this is an object
   FilteredCars: [] // this is an array, but array of what?
}
```

The `FilteredCars` property should be `Array<T>` where `T` is what this is an array of, in this case `FilteredCarsProps`.

```
type FilteredCarsProps = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  address: string
}

interface initialStateProps {
  isFiltered: boolean,
  Filters : object,
  FilteredCars: Array<FilteredCarsProps> <-- this should be fine
}
```

Comment: When writing the types, generally you copy paste what ever your object looks like in this case

```
interface initialStateProps {
  isFiltered: true, // i change true to boolean
  Filters : {}, // this is an object
  FilteredCars: [] // this is an array, but array of what, Array<T> here your T is what this is an array of, in this case FilteredCarsProps 
}
```

-sorry comment formatting is bad here-

Comment: Thanks man , really helping into my journey from JS to TS